# What is your expected behaviour in the next case (interval inclusions)?

Tags: c#, datetime, intervals

I was looking for some clarifications about intervals behaviour and what the people (developers) thinks about the end points inclusion.

When we talk about intervals of time (example: from 01.00 to 02.00 for example) I think we all think this is and end exclusion: "mathematically" `[01:00, 02:00)`. I think this is clear and simple. If not, tell me why.

But when we talk about intervals of dates (example: from 14.03.2019 to 22.05.2020) I don't know what behaviour the people expect. I usually think like `[14.3.2019, 22.5.2020]`. That means `23:59:59.999, 22.5.2020` is included, like the expression: `[14.3.2019, 23.5.2020)`.

The question is about this code snippet (simplified):

```
public class DateInterval{

    public readonly DateTime Start;
    public readonly DateTime End;
    //Enum (0= both, 1= start, 2= end)
    private readonly EndPointInclusionBehaviour _behaviour


    private DateTimeInterval(DateTime start, DateTime end){
        //Obvious
        Start= start.Date;

        //This is grinding my gears, have I to do this?
        End= end.Date.AddDays(1); 
        _behaviour = EndPointInclusionsBehaviour.IncludeStart;

        //Or this?
        End= end.Date.AddMilliseconds(-1);
        _behaviour = EndPointInclusionsBehaviour.IncludeBoth;

        //Or even this?
        End= end.Date;
        _behaviour = EndPointInclusionBehaviour.IncludeStart;

        //or this?
        End= end.Date.AddDays(1).AddMilliseconds(-1);
        _behaviour = EndPointInclusionsBehaviour.IncludeBoth;
    }
}
```

What is the behaviour will you expect?

Comment: Normally when considering intervals from a computer perspective you wouldnt do 1-2, 2-3, 3-4 as an event at 3 is then in 2 intervals.  Hence the 59.999

Comment: I vote for `[14.03.2019 00:00:00.000, 23.05.2020 00:00:00.000)`

Comment: @BugFinder Then the expected behaviour is "AddMilliseconds(-1)"? But then the argument 'end' date even isn't included in the interval.

Comment: @DrkDeveloper true but usually 1-2 ends for 2.. so the 2 can start..

Comment: @vasily.sib Two diferent opinions in 60 seconds. I want to cry.

Comment: Think of a day, a day doesnt include 2 mindnights.. why would an hour include both  hours..

Comment: @BugFinder The question here is "if i say from 1st jan 2019 to 31th jan 2019"... is 31th jan 2019 23.59.999 included and the next interval must start at 1st Feb 2019? Or in the other hand 31th jan must not be included and can be the start of the next?

Comment: @DrkDeveloper not really, as the last mark of 31st Jan is 23.59.9999, in your case of intervals of an hour, you wouldnt include 1st feb in the date, because thats now feb, ergo, the interval of 60 minutes goes from 0-59.999

Comment: @BugFinder Then the most rational option is the second in the code snippet? Or event a new option `end.Date.AddDays(1).AddMilliseconds(-1); includeBoth`?

Comment: The miliseconds idea is a very bad one. Just use `<`, `>`  vs `<=`, `>=` when including or excluding

Answer (score 0):

I'd simply document it and name the constructor parameters in a self explanatory way:

```
public Interval(int lowerInclusiveBound, int upperExclusiveBound) { ... }
```

I wouldn't change my approach with dates. Make it obvious to the consumer, and he'll choose the bounds he actually needs.